# Solve T(n) = T(n-n/k)+n using summation

Tags: recursion, big-o, recurrence

I am currently trying to solve the above recurrence relation but am having trouble trying to decipher the pattern an rewrite it as a sum. Could anyone help me out?

k >= 0. T(n<=2) = 1.

This recurrence relation was obtained from an algorithm I wrote to obtain a single sorted array from an array that is k sorted (meaning that every k'th element is in sorted order). This algorithm runs at most k times. Each time k is reduced by one and every k'th element is added to another array. Finally each array is merged using the merge from merge sort (n time). This algorithm is called recursively until k = 0, meaning we have found each sorted sub array.

I have a feeling that this is O(k*n), but I am not sure.

Comment: Whats the base case

Comment: @MitchelPaulin I don't think it needs one; it looks like it's meant to be an infinite sum.

Comment: @HTNW then I guess it would depend on the choice of k; for k < 0 this certainly doesn't converge

Comment: @MitchelPaulin see edit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a mathematics question, not a computer programming question.

Answer (score 1):

It might help to note that

> n - n/k = ((k - 1) / k)n,

so your recurrence relation represents n decaying geometrically by a factor of (k-1)/k at each step. To see how much work is done, let a = (k-1)/k. Then the work done is upper-bounded by

> n + an + a<sup>2</sup>n + a<sup>3</sup>n + ...
>
> = n / (1 - a)
>
> = n / (1 / k)
>
> = nk.

So your total work is O(nk).

As a note, I haven’t checked whether the recurrence relation you have matches your code - I’m just showing the math here. :-)

Comment: Awesome thanks. I got to the point of realizing it might be a geometric series, but I got thrown off by the + n term in the original recurrence relation.